# How to disable clicking parent menu item without disabling it?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I want to disable some of parent top menu links with sub-menus, so that when I click at the root top nothing should happen until I navigate and click to its sub menus for specific action.

For example, In Cocoa, if I have menu File -> Recent -> "...Recent files list...." , I can press "Recent". I want to prevent pressing "Recent". Can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is call [menuItem SetAction : 0] for the item having Sub Menus. 
In this way you will not be able to select this item.